# Online   bankruptcy filing?

Tags: united-states, bankruptcy, online-tools

There are many online tax websites (e.g., TurboTax), but are there similar websites for helping one [file for bankruptcy *pro se*](https://www.uscourts.gov/services-forms/bankruptcy/filing-without-attorney) (individually, without an attorney)?

<sup>Note: I'm not looking for "**product or service recommendations**…because [they tend to become obsolete quickly](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)", but simply whether such tools exist for filing for bankruptcy in one's particular State.</sup>

Comment: Bankruptcy is unrelated to tax filings. Taxes are filed to the IRS, bankruptcy to a court. Your local court might or might not have online filing pages, it depends on where you live.

Comment: Even if your local bankruptcy court permits online filings, it's *highly* recommended that you get a bankruptcy lawyer to navigate the process. It's very easy to muck it all up, and the consequences of doing so are far greater than a mistake on your taxes tends to result in.

Comment: @Aganju Yes, I realize that.

Answer (score 2):

No there probably aren’t websites like that. Because of the serious long term financial and legal consequences of bankruptcy and the great difficulty of succeeding with filing bankruptcy by yourself(paraphrasing from the instructions), you should hire an attorney to help. It is highly unlikely a website would be willing to take on the legal risk of the mistakes that could be made with the process.

The [forms and their instructions](https://www.uscourts.gov/forms/bankruptcy-forms) are available though.

Comment: "_the great difficulty of succeeding with filing bankruptcy by yourself_": "about 25% of cases filed without attorneys are dismissed" (USBCAZ, ["Implications of Filing Without Attorney Representation" @2:02](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7QkFROrg_BE#t=2m2s), from USBCAZ, "[Filing Without an Attorney](https://azb.uscourts.gov/filing-without-attorney)"). A 75% success rate is very good.

Comment: @Geremia "Not dismissed" doesn't mean "success". It may also mean "unfavorable decision reached". In fact, very likely.

Comment: @littleadv Well, by "success" I mean "having gone through the process correctly". Sure, the judge could pass an unfavorable decision, but could've a bankruptcy lawyer really helped make that decision favorable instead?

Comment: @Geremia yes, very much so.